# Change Parse PFQueryTableViewController Cells' Style

Tags: ios, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I currently use PFQueryTableViewController, and my `UITableView` looks like a standard `TableView`  I would prefer it look like one rounded rectangle per item in the view.  Per answer below, my code is currently:

**Cell.m**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(1,1,69,69);


}
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellWithName:(NSString *)name contentString:(NSString *)content
{
    CGSize contentSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin // wordwrap?
                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]}
                                               context:nil].size;

        return 10 + 50 + 10 + contentSize.height + 10 + 20 + 10 + 30;
}
```

**PFQueryTableViewController**

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
     PFObject *entry = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *commentString = entry[@"Request"];
    NSString *nameString = @"";
    NSLog(@"%@", commentString);
    return [Cell heightForCellWithName:nameString contentString:commentString] + 50;
}
```

Doing so returns this:

[image]

**Update**

Though the main issues are solved, I noticed that if contentLabel.text is too large, it starts covering up the likeButton and commentButtons.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your going to have to set the height of the cell dynamically according to the content of the text... I have done this with my project as well and its quite simple... Create a custom UITableviewcell that has a class method `+(CGFloat)heightForCellWith:(NSString *)content` and return call it when returning the height of the currently visible cell... Heres some sample code

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *commentString = [self.objects[indexPath.row] objectForKey:kPHGlobalChatTextKey];
    PFUser *commentAuthor = (PFUser *)[object objectForKey:kPHGlobalChatUserKey];
    NSString *nameString = @"";
    if (commentAuthor) {
        nameString = [commentAuthor objectForKey:kPHUserDisplayNameKey];
    }
    return [PHChatCell heightForCellWithName:nameString contentString:commentString] + 50;
}
```

Basically I am setting the height of the cell according to the text passed in... Heres how the method is implemented:

```
+ (CGFloat)heightForCellWithName:(NSString *)name contentString:(NSString *)content
{
    CGSize contentSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 20.0, CGFLOAT_MAX)
                                               options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin // wordwrap?
                                            attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]}
                                               context:nil].size;

/*
 * header spacing
 * profile picture
 * spacing
 * content
 * spacing
 * like/comment label
 * spacing
 * like/comment button
 */

    return 10 + 50 + 10 + contentSize.height + 10 + 20 + 10 + 30;
}
```

As you can see, I don't even use the user's name to determine the height of the cell, just the content of the string passed into the method...

Heres a pic of the result...

[image]

And yes... when creating the label... you need `[label numberOfLines:0]` to be set.

***EDIT***

Check out the cell I use for the screenshot... It should clear things up for you and give you a better understand of whats going on... How the labels are laid out and how everything is set...

[Cell url](https://github.com/jsetting32/SocialCell)

There is a method that is not included within the Cell class that calls `PHUtility`. just comment that out and your good to go... It basically handles how the date should be formatted with respect to the current date.

***Edit***

Where the content labels height is set, change the value to this...

```
CGSize contentSize = [content boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 40.0, FLT_MAX)
                                           options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                        attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0f]}
                                           context:nil].size;
```

Notice the `-40`... There are two places you need to change this in, layoutsubviews and the heightForCell class method

Set the NSFontAttributeName to whatever you like, just make sure your return the same CGSize variable in the heightForCell class method and in layoutsubviews.

Since the cell view's x value origin is at 10 and the content label is within the cell view where the content labels x origin value is also 10, within the main screen the actual x value is 20, so the width needs to be the width of the main screen -40.

Also, heres the method I use to format the date a little better...

```
#pragma mark - Date formatters
+(NSDateFormatter *)timeFormatter
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceMark;
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceMark, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"h:mm a"];
    });

    return formatter;
}

+(NSDateFormatter *)formatter
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceMark;
    static NSDateFormatter *formatter = nil;

    dispatch_once(&onceMark, ^{
        formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"MMMM d 'at' h:mm a"];
    });

    return formatter;
}
+ (NSString *)relativeDateStringForDate:(NSDate *)date
{

#ifdef __IPHONE_8_0
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear;
#else
    NSCalendarUnit units = NSDayCalendarUnit | NSWeekOfYearCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit;
#endif

    // if `date` is before "now" (i.e. in the past) then the components will be positive
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:units
                                                                   fromDate:date
                                                                     toDate:[NSDate date]
                                                                    options:0];



    if (components.year > 0) {
        return [[PHUtility formatter] stringFromDate:date];
    } else if (components.month > 0) {
        return [[PHUtility formatter] stringFromDate:date];
    } else if (components.weekOfYear > 0) {
        return [[PHUtility formatter] stringFromDate:date];
    } else if (components.day > 0) {
        return (components.day == 1) ?
        [[PHUtility formatter] stringFromDate:date] :
        [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yesterday at %@", [[PHUtility timeFormatter] stringFromDate:date]];
    }

    if (components.year == 0 && components.month == 0 && components.weekOfYear == 0 && components.day == 0){
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Today at %@", [[PHUtility timeFormatter] stringFromDate:date]];
    }

    return nil;
}
```

***Edit***

To help with your button selection issue, your going to have to RE-SET the UIButtons background color everytime the user has set a prayer...

Heres how I have implemented the method for the sake of your problem:

```
- (void)setLikeStatus:(BOOL)liked {

    [self.likeButton setSelected:liked];

    if (liked) {
        [self.likeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonLikeSelected.png"]];
        [self.likeButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
        return;
    }

    [self.likeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"ButtonLike.png"]];
    [self.likeButton setBackgroundColor:buttonColor];
}
```

Comment: Just a couple questions regarding your code, and how I would be able to edit it slightly to get the dynamic stuff set.  My table view only has 2 areas it needs text, both from the `PFObject`.  How would I be able to tweak your code to make the title view  the Title from this, and the detail the Request key from `PFObject`

Comment: I tried working with what you put in but it was all a big jumbled mess.

Comment: I updated my original question with an update showing the code I have used, along with the resulting image.

Comment: you need to set the x origin of your text label and detail text label to 10 or something like that as well as the text alignment to left

Comment: in addition, you need not to have a height that large... adjust the heightForCellName: method to your needs... mess around with it

Comment: also set UITableViewSeperator Style to UITableViewSeperatorStyleNone

Comment: Ok, I am really not following you very well, I don't think.  I currently have a method to layout the subviews.  Do I need that, AND the method you suggested, or just one of those?  Every time I try and do what you suggest, it looks NOTHING like pictures you have posted.  Also, I thought the whole `heightForCellName` method was to make it dynamic for each `PFObject` in the `PFQuery`.  How am I supposed to set that to something static and expect my cells to come out different?

Comment: To keep things more easily read, I updated the entire OP to show the current way things are.

Comment: To clarify... is may seem that I am using static int values to layout the subview but content label is being set according to the text passed in... You will notice that when you check out the repo I linked

Comment: Nevermind on that, finally saw where it was setting font size in layoutSubviews and that difference was causing the issue.

Comment: One thing I don't get is how the text for the Like and Comment UIButtons change.  I have the delegates all set where they will perform an action, but can't figure out how in yours it changes from Like to Liked or displays a different image, or shows a count.

Comment: I figure I can copy and paste some code for you but its pretty hefty... You should check out the Anypic project Parse has... Thats how I basically learned to do everything you need done... Your going to have to dive in NSCache, and PFCachePolicy. Both of which Anypic uses to improve performance and limit api requests to the server

Comment: Check out the classes PAPCache, PAPUtility and PAPPhotoTimelineViewController. If your having issues post another question and message me

Comment: Last issue on this, I swear...if the contentLabel.text gets really long, it starts covering up the likeButton and commentButton very gradually.  Can't figure out where in my layoutSubviews I have it screwed up like that.

Comment: Haha no problem... I like how Im gaining a lot of rep today :)... Could you make and edit to your post by adding a picture please.

Comment: Ok, I have it up now.  I tried tweaking by adding + 15 to the return part heightForCellWithContentString.  For this specific long request it worked, but for the shorter one beneath, it added gray space underneath the buttons.

Comment: I added a date formatter to handle the time of the prayer post of the cell... use it if you like

Comment: And no prob! Here to help

Comment: Cool, will check it out.  There any way to change not just the color of the word Pray when it is selected, but the entire background color?  In beta testing, my users aren't sure if they push it or not, so the action gets called over and over again, delivering many push notifications to me that they're praying, lol.

Comment: Or really any suggestions at all to tell EU that the button was pressed.  I don't want to do UIAlertView, as that gets old quick.

Comment: Check the edit... Basically change the background color when the like status changes... You should be calling `setLikeStatus:` or `setPrayerStatus:` when your user has pressed the button... At least thats what I do for the like button

Comment: So in my case, the self.likeButton is what I would put in instead of self.likeImage?  Or would this be the yourPlusSign?

Comment: Oh yeah... I made some changes, instead of yourPlusSign, I declared a property names likeImage... So yeah... your right

Comment: Cool, got it to change the color of the little hands I have next to Pray from black to red (using two different images) when that likeButton is clicked.  Is there a way that change can be persisted between launches?  Like the phone is rebooted and then it still remembers you have prayed for that?  I'm not asking you to write that code for me, I'm just asking if that is one of the things setLikeStatus is supposed to do?

Comment: No, setLikeStatus just simply sets the status of the button... But it needs to be called/handled in the controller loading the cell... So within your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:object` method in your controller, thats where the initial setting of the prayer button should happen. There was a question you posted regarding the issue about highlighting the prayer button. I posted the code to handle that.